# Parse a dynamic xml file recursively in python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read a dynamic xml file recursively. Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlNavigator:
    def __init__(self, xml=None):
        self.tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()
        
    def parse_xml(self, node):
        for elem in self.root.iter():
            if elem.tag == f"{node}":
                return elem
                           
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_string = "<note> <to>Tove</to>    <from>Jani</from>    <heading>Reminder</heading>    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  </note>  "
    xmlObj = XmlNavigator(xml_string)
```

Here my `xml_string` is dynamic which can change and have different items and tags.

Now I want to print the items as follows in recursive manner:

```
<note>  
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from>  
  <heading>Reminder</heading>  
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  
</note>  

  <to>Tove</to>  
  
Tove

  <from>Jani</from>  
  
Jani
  
  <heading>Reminder</heading>  
 
Reminder 
  
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  

Don't forget me this weekend!
```

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this result, if you create the object and call the method which can  print your needs:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlNavigator:
    def __init__(self, xml=None):
        self.tree = tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml))
        self.root = tree.getroot()
        
    def parse_xml(self):
        for elem in self.root.iter():
            print(ET.tostring(elem).decode('utf8'))
            if elem.text != None:
                print(elem.text+'\n')
            else:
                print('None') # catch empty nodes like <body />
                           
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <note>
                      <to>Tove</to>
                      <from>Jani</from>
                      <heading>Reminder</heading>
                      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                    </note>"""
    xmlObj = XmlNavigator(xml_string)
    xmlObj.parse_xml()
```